# Simple excel VBA if- ifelse bug?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem with this VBA Excel code: 
=Area(A2,A3) doesn't return any value if A3 doesn't exist.

```
Function Area(Length, Optional Width)

    If IsMissing(Width) Then
        Area = Length * Length
    Else
        Area = Length * Width
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: =Area(A2) is working.
but i need it to give the same value as =Area(A2;A3) With A3 missing

Comment: i don't understand your question as I have tried your code in a fresh wb and your code works as seems to be intended (e.g. with 2 in A1 and 3 in B1: =Area(A1) -> 4, =Area(A1,B1) -> 6).

Comment: if you mean for =Area(A1,B1) when B1 is **blank** to be equivalent to =Area(A1) then add an additional test in before the Else clause of `Elseif Width = Empty Then: Area = Length * Length: Else...`

Comment: ok try a option explicit and declaring variables. first things first

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing IsMissing and IsEmpty.

If nothing is passed to the function, eg:  =Area(A1), then Width will be Missing.

But where you are passing an argument to the function, where B1 contains nothing:  =Area(A1,B1) then Width will be Empty, not Missing.

To handle both situations:

```
If IsMissing(Width) Or IsEmpty(Width) Then
    Area = Length * Length
Else
    Area = Length * Width
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

IsMissing does not work on simple data types (such as Integer or Double) because, unlike Variants, they don't have a provision for a "missing" flag bit. Because of this, the syntax for typed optional arguments allows you to specify a default value. If the argument is omitted when the procedure is called, then the argument will have this default value, as in the example below:

Maybe this can help:

```
Function Area(Length, Optional Width as String = "missing")
    If Width = "missing" Then
        Area = Length * Length
    Else
        Area = Length * Width
    End If

End Function
```

from:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/access-help/ismissing-function-HA001228866.aspx

Comment: Why do you think Width is a Integer or Double data type?

Comment: Because he's calculating an Area?

Comment: When a variable type is not declared, it will be a variant (see VBA Help). To demonstrate this. set a Watch expression on Length or Width, you will see that they are of type Variant Subtype Integer (or Error)..  It looks like Variant/Integer  or Variant/Error or whatever.  So IsMissing and IsEmpty will work on these variables.  (Vartype will pick up the subtype in the case of Variants).